# How does SQLite behave when inserting unordered hashes as the rowid?

Tags: sql, sqlite

According to the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) on `rowid` the data for `rowid` tables is stored in a B-tree. I’ve been considering using a hash of my data as the `rowid`. Since this means I’d be inserting rows with `rowid`s that are not ordered like the default implementation of `rowid` how will this impact `INSERT` and `SELECT` performance in addition to the layout of data in my table?

If I insert a row which has a large `rowid` because it’s a hash and then a row with a smaller `rowid` what will the table layout look like?

Comment: what hash? something like GUID, UUID or SHA hashes?

Comment: It would be a SHA hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend upon how.

If you do not define an alias for the rowid column and a **VACUUM** takes place then the **rowid** values will likely be messed up (as they may/will be re-assigned).

e.g. :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablex;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablex (data TEXT);
INSERT INTO tablex (rowid,data) VALUES(82356476978,'fred'),(55,'mary');
SELECT rowid AS therowid,* FROM tablex;
VACUUM;
SELECT rowid AS therowid,* FROM tablex;
```

results in :-

[image]

and then :-

[image]

If an alias is defined the VACUUM shouldn't be an issue and as above, it's fine to do so.

Of course you have to adhere to the rules and as long as the rules are obeyed, that is that the values are unique integers and are not greater than 9223372036854775807 or less than -9223372036854775808, then it should be fine. Other values would result in a datatype mismatch error.

I don't believe there would be much of an impact upon performance, there could possibly even be an improvement as there may well be space free in leaves reducing the need for a more costly split.

e.g. the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tabley;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabley (myrowidalias INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,data TEXT);
INSERT INTO tabley VALUES(9223372036854775807,'fred'),(-9223372036854775808,'Mary'),(55,'Sue');
SELECT rowid AS therowid,* FROM tabley;
VACUUM;
SELECT rowid AS therowid,* FROM tabley;

-- INSERT INTO tabley VALUES(9223372036854775808,'Sarah'); -- Dataype mismatch
INSERT INTO tabley VALUES(-9223372036854775809,'Bob'); -- Datatype mismatch
SELECT rowid AS therowid,* FROM tabley; -- not run due to above error
```

Results in (note rowid retrieved via rowid and it's alias) :-

[image]

and after the VACUUM (identical) :-

[image]

With message :-

```
-- INSERT INTO tabley VALUES(9223372036854775808,'Sarah');
INSERT INTO tabley VALUES(-9223372036854775809,'Bob')
> datatype mismatch
> Time: 0s
```